# Why there aren't any squares of 2 divisible by 3?

Tags: proof-verification, divisibility

A friend of mine recently told me that it is not possible to perfectly divide a cake in three pieces because 1/3 is an repeating decimal. Now, this is clearly a silly statement as 0.33333... is an repeating decimal but it is a real number nonetheless. My friend is right in the sense that is not possible to divide a cake in any "perfect" way, e.g. in two halves; more precisely, it is not possible to measure anything "perfectly" so that you will never know if you division was actually perfectly accurate.

I wanted to prove my friend wrong using the following argument: let's imagine you are right, you cannot divide a cake in three pieces but you can divide it in two pieces. Then you can divide those two pieces in two pieces and so on. At one point, you are going to have x pieces of cakes where x is divisible by three. Thus, your original statement must be false. While I was thinking this, however, I noticed that there is no number $2^n$ that can be divided by three without a remainder.

Has this been proved (I guess so)? Is there any intuitive explanation?

Comment: 1/3 is not irrational at all!

Comment: [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic) explains why $2^n$ is not divisible by $3$.

Comment: Sorry, oversights. I corrected everything.

Comment: Clarification: The set of rational numbers is $\mathbb{Q}=\left\{\frac{a}{b}: a,b\in\mathbb{Z}, b\neq 0\right\}$.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I corrected the post, as I intended "repeating decimal" and not "irrational". Now it should make sense.

Comment: John Habert's link explains why. As an aside: To convince him, ask him to represent $1/3$ in base $3$, then ask him why base $10$ is *special* but $3$ isn't.

Comment: Related: [Is it possible to 'split' coin flipping 3 ways?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2356/is-it-possible-to-split-coin-flipping-3-ways) asks if there is a way to choose between *three* alternatives with equal probability by flipping a coin or coins. The answer is not with a finite number of flips, for essentially the same reason.

Answer (score 9):

To divide a cake equally among three persons, using only divisions in half:

1. Divide the cake in half twice, producing 4 equal pieces.
2. Give one equal piece to each person.
3. Using the same method, divide the remaining piece equally among the three persons.

Comment: Truly a parsimonious solution.

Comment: I am afraid I do not get this. You divide your cake in four pieces, fine. You give one pieces to each person, then you divide the remaining piece into four. Now, if you give one of these sub-pieces to each person, you remain with one sub-piece. Am I missing something?

Comment: The method has three steps. When you divide the leftover piece, using the same method, you have to use all three steps. Your description above stopped after step 2.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [Fundamental theorem of arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic), every integer greater than $1$ has a **unique** prime factorization. Since $2$ and $3$ are prime, $2^n$ ($n>0$) is *already* **the** prime factorization, and does not have $3$ as a factor. Hence it is not divisible by $3$.

Answer (score 3):

$2^n/3=2\cdot2\cdot\ldots\cdot2/3$. Proof by induction:

Let $n=1$. $2/3$ is just $0$ with remainder $2$. Hence, there exists a remainder for $2/3$.

How about $2^{n+1}/3$? Using the previous proof that $2/3$ has a remainder, and expanding $2^{n+1}/3$ as $2^n\left(2/3\right)$ shows that $2^{n+1}/3$ has a remainder. Therefore, $\forall n, 2^n/3$ has a remainder.