# Flipping coin(s) to decide who pays the bill

Tags: probability, random, binary

I'm not from a mathematical background. I found this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2EbanrRUuy0&src_vid=usYC_Z36rHw&feature=iv&annotation_id=annotation_1123420099) on YouTube rather confusing. I know basics of probability from school.
My question: If a single coin is flipped among 3 people say A, B and C with following combination

Say between A & B first

> Between A & B

and then

> Between A(or)B and C //depending on whether A or B loses in the first toss

how would that not be fair.

In the first instance, when coin is tossed between A & B - the probability of A or B paying the bill is 50% each.
Likewise, in the second instance when the coin is tossed between the loser of first instance (which could be A or B) and C - the probability is again 50% each.
Hence, a fair deal.
I do not understand why the speaker in the beginning of the video says **it would not be fair** and requires the person to be selected using "binary randomness"
*Feel free to edit the question, if it has not been worded well*

Comment: I though this was a duplicate of [Is it possible to 'split' coin flipping 3 ways?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2356/is-it-possible-to-split-coin-flipping-3-ways), but it isn't.

Comment: @MJD Thanks for the link. However, I would want to know why would it be unfair to do it by elimination as per my question

Comment: $C$ has a chance of $0.5$ to become the one who has to pay the bill. The others have a chance of $0.25$. That is not really fair, is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose we agree that we will always toss the coin twice, and then follow the schedule you described:

1. Between $A$ and $B$: $A$ loses on heads, $B$ loses on tails
2. Between $C$ and the loser of toss 1: $C$ loses on heads, the round 1 loser loses on tails

There are four ways the coin could come up, all equally likely:

$$\begin{array}{cc|c}
\text{first toss} & \text{second toss} & \text{loser} \\ \hline
H & H  & C \\
H & T & A \\
T & H & C \\
T & T & B
\end{array}
$$
We see from the chart that $C$ pays half the time, and one of $A$ or $B$ pays the other half the time, which is only $\frac14$ each.  Then $C$ is paying twice as often as $A$ or $B$ is.

It should be clear that $C$ has a disadvantage: to get stuck with the check, $A$ must lose two coin tosses, but $C$ is stuck with the check if she loses one coin toss, which is easier than losing two.

In fact there is no perfectly fair way to chose among three people with a finite number of coin tosses.  But the following method works well:

$$\begin{array}{cc|c}
\text{first toss} & \text{second toss} & \text{loser} \\ \hline
H & H  & A \\
H & T & B \\
T & H & C \\
T & T & \text{flip again}
\end{array}
$$

Several other methods are described in [Is it possible to 'split' coin flipping 3 ways?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2356/is-it-possible-to-split-coin-flipping-3-ways)

Comment: The answer as per your suggestion was also suggested in the http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2EbanrRUuy0&src_vid=usYC_Z36rHw&feature=iv&annotation_id=annotation_1123420099. Thanks a ton!