# Probability of encountering {tail, head, tail} before {tail, tail, head} in consecutive flips of an unbiased coin.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

I was reading the second answer for [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2356/is-it-possible-to-split-coin-flipping-3-ways) question. I wondered why the probability of encountering THT before TTH is 1/3 ?

Comment: The probability is the same as for encountering HTH before HHT, which is worked out in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2864051/which-pattern-comes-before-tossing-fair-coins . Also look up "Penney's game".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the first T, we have:

- T* with probability $\frac12$ (any number of T's followed by H yields TTH)
- HT with probability $\frac14$ (yielding THT)
- HH with probability $\frac14$ (returning to the initial state)

\begin{align}P(TTH) &= 0.5 + 0.25*P(TTH)\\
0.75*P(TTH) &= 0.5\\
P(TTH) &= 2/3\\[3ex]
P(THT) &= 0.25 + 0.25*P(THT)\\
0.75*P(THT) &= 0.25\\
P(THT) &= 1/3\end{align}