# Lower bound of generating a biased coin?

Tags: probability

If we have an unbiased coin and we want to generate a biased coin with probability $p$ of getting a head and $1-p$ of getting a tail. What is the lower bound of the expected number of flips that generating this biased coin?

Comment: As a function of $p$?

Comment: For which simulation algorithm?

Comment: DidierPiau: Not a specific kind, just to find out a lower bound

Comment: $1$ is a lower bound; $2$ is an upper bound for the expectation.  What do you mean by *the* lower bound?

Comment: I guess you are looking for [entropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_%28information_theory%29), in such case you need $p\log_2 (p) + (1-p)\log_2(1-p)$ coin flips to get your result (note that for $p\in [0,1]$ the result is in $[0,1]$ too, i.e. for $p \neq 0.5$ you will need less than one coin flip). (In other cases, what happens if $p$ is transcendental?)

Answer (score 2):

*This answer concerns the maximal (rather than expected) number of tosses; which is not what is asked for.*

---

After flipping a fair coin $n$ times, you have $2^n$ equally likely outcomes. Every event defined in terms of these outcomes has probability   $k/2^n$ for some $k\in\{0,\dots,2^n\}$. And conversely, for every $k$ there is such an event. Conclusion:

> Required number of flips is $ \inf\{n: 2^np\in\mathbb Z\}$.

Which is infinite when $p$ is not a dyadic rational; meaning that for such $p$ you can't simulate the  biased coin at all.

Example: if $p=0.375$, you need $3$ flips.

Comment: This is not correct: note that the problem says "expected number of coin flips". E.g. you can simulate a biased coin with $p = \frac13$ (which is not a dyadic rational) by the process of flipping a coin twice, saying "heads" if you see "HH", "tails" if you see "HT" or "TH", and repeating the experiment if you see "TT". This has probability $\frac14$ of requiring yet another pair of flips, but the *expected* number of coin flips to terminate is $\frac43 (2) = 8/3$, not infinite. See e.g. [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1333/) (there are probably others too on math.SE).

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Good point; would you like to give a correct answer to this question?

Answer (score 1):

If you expand $p$ in binary, then take head of your flips as a $1$, tail as a $0$, you can state head or tail as soon as you disagree with $p$.  There is no lower bound, as the sequence of flips could match the expansion of $p$ as long as you want.  Say $p=\frac 13=0.01010101\overline{01}_2$.  As long as you alternate tails and heads you can't tell.  With probability $1$ that will stop sometime.  The expected number of flips is $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac i{2^i}=2$

Comment: Lower bound on the _expected number_ of the flips is what the problem asks for. Did you mean "there is no upper bound"? (Which also should exist (in terms of $p$), I guess?) And are you saying that that the expected number of flips is $2$ irrespective of the value of $p$? Something seems wrong with that... I haven't thought through this clearly, but e.g. if $p = \frac1{100}$ I suspect we'll need at least 7 flips (and probably more).

Comment: Actually now I understand why you say there is no lower bound: in the case of $p=\frac1{100}$ for instance, there is *less* information than in the $p=\frac12$ case, because most of the time we can just say "tails". (I was earlier thinking of the $(\frac1{100}, \frac1{100}, \dots, \frac1{100})$ distribution rather than the $(\frac1{100}, \frac{99}{100})$ distribution we care about here.) However, there is still a lower bound *in terms of $p$,* I think it's $H(p)/H(\frac12)$ i.e. $p\lg\frac1p+(1-p)\lg\frac1{1-p}$. This is $< 1$ though.