# What is the "hardest" random choice for coin flips to make?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, logarithms

Using a coin, the goal is to choose from n choices randomly. Define the "difficulty" of the task of choosing from n choices randomly as (the minimum expected value of number of coin flips) - $\log_2(n)$. Which $n$ maximizes the "difficulty"? It has been proven in [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1333/is-there-a-possibility-to-choose-fairly-from-three-items-when-every-choice-can-o) that it takes at least $8/3$ flips on average to choose from $3$ random options, which gives a difficulty of about $1.08$.

Comment: According to the Knuth and Yao paper mentioned in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1357/177399), (corollary to theorem 2.2), the difficulty is always at most $2$.

Comment: Specifically, the difficulty is
$$n\cdot \nu(1/n)-\log_2 n,$$ where $\nu$ is a function defined in the paper. The graph of $\nu$ is highly discontinuous and chaotic. I therefore suspect there is no maximal difficulty; as $n\to\infty$, you will keep finding examples which are closer and closer to $2$, never reaching it.